# Arithmetic groups and integral points of integral structures

Tags: algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

If $\mathbf{G}$ is an algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, a subgroup of $\mathbf{G}(\mathbb{Q})$ is *arithmetic* if it is commensurable to $\mathbf{G}(\mathbb{Q}) \cap \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ where some representation $\mathbf{G} < \operatorname{GL}_n$ has been chosen (and the definition is made so that the choice does not matter).

Fur the purpose of this question let us call a subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\mathbf{G}(\mathbb{Q})$ *strictly arithmetic* if there exists a group $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme $\mathbf{G}_\mathbb{Z}$ with generic fiber $\mathbf{G}$ such that $\Gamma = \mathbf{G}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z})$.

I was recently asked the natural question whether strictly arithmetic is the same as arithmetic. I suspect that the answer is "no". More specifically arithmetic groups can be arbitrarily small (for instance have arbitrarily large covolume in $\mathbf{G}(\mathbb{R})$) while I suspect that this is not true of strictly arithmetic groups. But I don't know enough about group schemes to underpin that intuition. So I'm asking here:

**Original question: Are there (resp. what are) examples of arithmetic groups that are not strictly arithmetic?**

The original question was answered in the comments by David Loeffler using a different obstruction so let me (following YCor's suggestion in the comments) specifically ask:

**Additional question: Do there exist "arbitrarily small" strictly arithmetic subgroups, for instance in the sense that the covolume or injectivity radius in $\mathbf{G}(\mathbb{R})$ is arbitrarily large?**

Comment: Any "strictly arithmetic" subgroup in your sense will be a congruence subgroup. Noncongruence subgroups exist in $SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$, and lots of other groups too.

Comment: Since the current main question is answered in comments (non-congruence subgroups are not strictly arithmetic), you might emphasize the covolume question instead (are there strictly arithmetic subgroups of arbitrary large covolume? arbitrary large systole?)?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: It seems difficult to me to define a congruence subgroup of $\textbf{G}(\mathbb{Z})$ without an integral structure. So can I read you assertion as saying "the intersection of two strictly arithmetic subgroups is a congruence subgroup in either"? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Congruence subgroup = intersection of $G(\mathbb{Q})$ with an open compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb{A}_f)$. No need for integral structures.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: I seem to remember hearing that congruence subgroups are exactly the strictly arithmetic groups as defined in the question, at least if the group scheme $\mathbf{G}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is assumed to be smooth and finite type. I have not thought about the proof, but have the feeling that it is not difficult. If anyone cares, I can ask the person who told me this "fact". (The implication from strictly arithmetic to congruence (say with the smoothness condition) is of course easy.)

Comment: Are you sure about this? The restriction that $G_\mathbb{Z}$ be smooth (integrally) seems a bit strong.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: I was not able to find a precise reference, but I think the claim should follow from the following local statement by a patching argument: if $G$ is a reductive group over a local field $F$ and $K \subset of G(F)$ a compact open subgroup then there is a smooth integral model of $G$ such that $K$ is the set of integral points. See, for example, section 2 of "Smooth models associated to concave functions in Bruhat-Tits theory" by J.-K. Yu. (This might require that the adelic group be a product of local groups.)

Comment: I looked in Yu's paper (link: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=F8805D95A2779DC3FC8F1819CA33222E?doi=10.1.1.370.1790&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and I didn't find the statement you have claimed. Could you be more precise with the reference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First question** (do non-strictly-arithmetic subgroups exist?):

Any "strictly arithmetic" subgroup in your sense will, in particular, be a congruence subgroup, i.e. the intersection of $G(\mathbb{Q})$ with an open compact subgroup in $G(\mathbb{A}_f)$. Since non-congruence subgroups exist in $SL_2 / \mathbb{Q}$, and in lots of other groups too, these are examples of arithmetic subgroups which are not strictly arithmetic.

**Second question** (can strictly arithmetic subgroups be small?):

Start with your favourite $GL_n$-embedding $\iota$, defining some strictly arithmetic $\Gamma$. Take some $g \in G(\mathbb{Q})$ which isn't in $\Gamma$, and consider the embedding into $GL_{2n}$ sending $h$ to the block-diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \iota(h) \\&  \iota(g^{-1} h g))\end{pmatrix}$. This defines a new $\mathbb{Z}$-model of $G$ whose integral points are $\Gamma \cap g \Gamma g^{-1}$. If $G = SL_2$, and probably for just about any $G$ which isn't abelian, the index of $\Gamma \cap g \Gamma g^{-1}$ in $\Gamma$ can be made arbitrarily large by a suitable choice of $\Gamma$.